# Linq Expression Iterator source

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a question on how the `WhereListIterator`  in C# works.
Example: When I use the where select like in this case:

```
var itemsNull = products.Where(p => p.ItemId == 0).Select(ell => ell.SKU);
```

The `itemsNull`  is of type `WhereListIterator`.
This class contains a source property. I am wondering if the source contains a copy of the products List.

Comment: If by *copy* you mean a deep copy then no, none of the linq operators make a deep copy of the source enumeration. Rather, it's just a reference.

Comment: yes i meant a deep copy, when you allocate a memory for a second object.
So i conclude that no, it does not.

Comment: I find the [C# Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) helpful for these sorts of questions.

Answer (score 0):

If saying simply, LINQ expressions are not performed until they are needed, so `itemsNull` contains only a reference to your expression on source property and will be performed just when you iterate your variable via `foreach` or other LINQ expression.

You can force your expression to perform immediately by adding `.ToList()` at the end (because `ToList()` also iterates the IEnumerable).